# Will task sleep during the memory access?

Tags: linux, memory, sleep, schedule

I suppose this should be a programming question. I just want to make sure, in the current Linux scheduler, will the task sleep(or dequeued) when it's waiting for the memory IO? In other words, will the memory IO waiting time be counted as this task's CPU occupation time?
I am pretty sure that when there is a page fault with a disk IO, the task will go to sleep. But I am not quite sure about the memory access.

Comment: What exact kind of memory IO are you thinking of? Most memory IO is very fast.... (e.g. accessing to the memory of your graphics card is a few times slower than accessing your ordinary RAM).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Hi, thanks for your reply.I understand. But let us just assume there is a relatively long memory access(try to bring some memory blocks into the cache line). Then the process needs to wait,right? But I suppose at this time, there would be no context switch and the current thread would be like busy waiting on the CPU. Do you know whether this is true?

Comment: No, if you are thinking of on-chip processor cache misses, the kernel don't handle them (only the hardware does). So technically the process is not even stalled (it is running from the point of view of the kernel). However, some Intel chips provide two "hardware threads" (= register sets) per core, giving the illusion of having 2 times the number of cores. On those chips, the other hardware thread (of the same core) can run during a cache miss. Don't be confused by the terminology: hardware threads are not kernel tasks (but are virtual cores, from the point of view of the kernel).